# What kind of equations can use the comma-goes-to-semicolon rule?

Tags: differential-geometry, differentiation, covariance

I am wondering what kind of equations in Minkowski spacetime can transform into a curved spacetime by using the comma-goes-to-semicolon rule.

For example, consider the Schrodinger's equation for a free particle, $$i\hbar \partial \psi /\partial t=-(\hbar^2/2m)\nabla^2 \psi,$$ can I just use the comma-goes-to-semicolon rule to replace those partial derivatives by covariant derivatives, yielding

$$i\hbar  \psi _{;0} =-(\hbar^2/2m) g^{ij}\psi_{;i;j}$$

where $i$ and $j$ run in spatial coordinates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs to be an equation that's Lorentz-invariant in special relativity, so the TDSE is unsuitable as it's Galilean-invariant instead.

There are also further subtleties even for Lorentz-invariant equations. For example, how does the "flat" Klein-Gordon equation $\phi_{,\mu}^{,\mu}=-m^2\phi$ (assuming $+---$) change? Well, we've already made it manifestly covariant, so the LHS becomes $\phi_{;\mu}^{;\mu}$. The RHS, however, may generalize; for example, with minimal coupling to the Ricci scalar, it becomes $-(m^2+\xi R)\phi$.

Comment: How about ordering ambiguities when promoting or solely to covariant derivatives?

Comment: @innisfree Do you have in mind examples such as upgrading $F^{\mu\nu}_{,\mu}=A^{\nu,\mu}_{,\mu}-A^{\mu,\nu}_{,\mu}$ so the subtracted term becomes either $A^{\mu;\nu}_{;\mu}$ or $A^\mu{}_{;\mu}{}^{;\nu}$? If so, you need considerations such as preserving symmetries or deriving it from a Lagrangian. The first answer is right, BTW.